# from torchvision.datasets.vision import VisionDataset ImportError: No module named vision

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I am new to pytorch, and I am trying to follow guides ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467781/pytorch-dataloader-for-image-gt-dataset)) that start with:

```
from torchvision.datasets.vision import VisionDataset
```

or

```
from .vision import VisionDataset
```

When I try to run it I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named vision
```

In addition, It seems that torchvision.datasets.vision is not mentioned in any documentation.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of PyTorch are you using?

Comment: My PyTorch version is 0.4.0

Comment: and torchvision?

Comment: torchvision 0.2.1

Comment: I don't see any "vision" mentioned at the [documentation of torchvision](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/) , so I don't think that updating torchvision might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your `torchvision` package as `VisionDataset` was introduced in torchvision 0.3.0 in [PR#749](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/749) as a base class for all datasets. Check the [release](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases/tag/v0.3.0).

Comment: I had to rebuild the entire virtual environment for this upgrade, but eventually it worked.
Thanks!